# Transferring a single iCloud account to family sharing

Tags: icloud, sharing

My partner has a basic iCloud account (200GB storage).  I have just bought the next level up and have invited them to share this new, larger space.

My Apple account shows that there are now two of us sharing my storage.  But my partner's Apple storage makes no mention of their now being on family sharing.  Instead it shows as still being what it always was (i.e. the 200GB they have always had).

I don't know what I need to do to give them access to my storage space?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to set up family sharing first, before you can share the space - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208147 Can't test, so not an answer for now.

Comment: @Tetsujin - thanks.  It looks as though what I want to do IS possible but only for for OSVentura (onwards).  Unless someone here has a work around...

Comment: Nothing in that article is Ventura only. If you (and they) both sign into iCloud.com and go to Account Settings, you can confirm the family setup, independent of the local device versions. If you're in a family successfully, there will be a section titled "Family Sharing" with an icon for each participant. You cannot manage anything here but you can confirm the current state.

Comment: On your device, go to the Family Sharing part of your settings and verify closely that their account appears alongside yours, that the email address is correct, and that nothing indicates it's pending.

Comment: @Ezekiel - thank you for your comments.  My partner IS on my family iCloud subscription list, but is marked 'Not using'.  She has her own iCloud storage account.  How can she safely transfer her stored iCloud info to mine?

Comment: @Dan She just needs to unsubscribe from her storage bundle and it should merge it in automatically so long as yours is marked as Sharing with the family it will pick it up automatically. I understand better your question now, I believe.

Comment: @Ezekiel - you and the Apple help chat line have solved the issue.  Thank you.